# Coffeescript: what does it mean to have curly brackets around a method parameter?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
checkbox: (propertyName, {hash}) ->
  ...
  ...
```

What does this mean?

I'm familiar with the concept of

```
class Person
  constructor: (name) ->
    @name = name
```

having a shorthand of

```
class Person
  constructor: (@name) ->
```

Does {parameterName} have similar magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [undocumented parameter destructuring](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1607)

```
(propertyName, {hash}) ->
```

Is short for -->

```
(propertyName, obj) ->
    hash = obj.hash
```

And this

```
(propertyName, {hash, something}) ->
```

Is short for -->

```
(propertyName, obj) ->
    hash = obj.hash
    something = obj.something
```

And so on. It works pretty much like the [normal destructuring](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
checkbox = (propertyName, {hash}) ->
```

compiles directly to this in JS

```
var checkbox;

checkbox = function(propertyName, _arg) {
  var hash;
  hash = _arg.hash;
};
```

So it gets the property of an object being passed in and sets it as the top level variable name.  Whether this is a good thing or not is up for debate, especially since it doesn't seem to be a documented language feature (that I can find)

Coffeescript's site has a helpful tool for investigating things like this: [Try Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3acheckbox%20%3D%20%28propertyName%2C%20%7Bhash%7D%29%20-%3E%0A)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, I recommend [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js) to check out the rendered output. You can also use [codepen](http://codepen.io/) to play around and find the results of certain actions. For example see this as a [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/Fresheyeball/pen/BuLrJ)

```
foo = (bar, {baz}) ->
  console.log bar+baz

opts = 
  qaz : 'hey'
  baz : 'wowzers'

foo "go go", opts

# console will log "go go wowzers"
```

renders to ->

```
var foo, opts;

foo = function(bar, _arg) {
  var baz;
  baz = _arg.baz;
  return console.log(bar + baz);
};

opts = {
  qaz: 'hey',
  baz: 'wowzers'
};

foo("go go", opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes it so you can directly use the options names instead of having to do options.property, ie

```
func = (someValue, {shouldDoSomething, doWork}) ->
   # use option names directly
   doWork someValue if shouldDoSomething
```

instead of

```
func = (someValue, options) ->
   options.doWork someValue if options.shouldDoSomething
```